# I am studying Robolectric but an error occured

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I am studying [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

My project dir is,
[image]

My unit test codes `MainActivityTest` are as follows,

```
package com.example.activity;

import android.app.Activity;

import com.example.BuildConfig;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

  @Test
  public void titleIsCorrect() throws Exception {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    assertTrue(activity.getTitle().toString().equals("Deckard"));
  }
}
```

The configuration is,
[image]

When I run the test code,
[image]

It goes wrong,

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51663,suspend=y,server=n -ea -javaagent:/Users/liren/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio1.2/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/Android Studio 2.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/liren/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res:/Users/liren/code/robolectric/RobolectricGo/android-api-19/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug:/Users/liren/code/robolectric/RobolectricGo/android-api-19/build/intermediates/classes/debug:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/b09be554228d66d208e5fef5266844aacf443abc/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.ant/ant/1.8.0/7b456ca6b93900f96e58cc8371f03d90a9c1c8d1/ant-1.8.0.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.assertj/assertj-core/1.7.0/c0451c7fce61d14f9f0fa84bb2760e548221e471/assertj-core-1.7.0.jar:/Users/liren/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/53.1/icu4j-53.1.jar:/Users/liren/.m2/repository/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/accessibility/framework/accessibility-test-framework/1.0/accessibility-test-framework-1.0.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric-annotations/3.0-SNAPSHOT/4e48c5059ce3fae922863f3464fa05ce6a5e08d6/robolectric-annotations-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.ant/ant-launcher/1.8.0/8b53ba16fa62fb1034da8f1de200ddc407c8381/ant-launcher-1.8.0.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/5.0.1/7b7147a390a93a14d2edfdcf3f7b0e87a0939c3e/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar:/Users/liren/.m2/repository/com/almworks/sqlite4java/sqlite4java/0.282/sqlite4java-0.282.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/5.0.1/1b1e6e9d869acd704056d0a4223071a511c619e6/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/5.0.1/2fd56467a018aafe6ec6a73ccba520be4a7e1565/asm-5.0.1.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis/5.0.1/e286fbee48efacb4e7c175f7948d9d8b2ab52352/asm-analysis-5.0.1.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric/3.0-SNAPSHOT/fde4745244f1447557b2f55030cb4fc546b53fac/robolectric-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/liren/.m2/repository/com/ximpleware/vtd-xml/2.11/vtd-xml-2.11.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/5.0.1/7c8caddfbd0b2d7b844f8fcc75175b9cb9cf4724/asm-util-5.0.1.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.1/860340562250678d1a344907ac75754e259cdb14/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46/ce091790943599535cbb4de8ede84535b0c1260c/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric-utils/3.0-SNAPSHOT/bf446c7a07ee47a454c8db9ad10c1a8ca2515fd9/robolectric-utils-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.10/e4f1766ce7404a08f45d859fb9c226fc9e41a861/junit-4.10.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric-resources/3.0-SNAPSHOT/ee905e9f06d0056f8d165a9a8ba24864825baa64/robolectric-resources-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/liren/kit/gradle-2.4/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/shadows-core/3.0-SNAPSHOT/419067a26312d0bd71b00d81fa4bc501f7ccdabd/shadows-core-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/liren/code/robolectric/RobolectricGo/android-api-19/build/intermediates/mockable-android-19.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.example.activity.MainActivityTest
objc[13827]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51663', transport: 'socket'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: build/intermediates/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.robolectric.res.FileFsFile.getInputStream(FileFsFile.java:78)
    at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.parseAndroidManifest(AndroidManifest.java:132)
    at org.robolectric.manifest.AndroidManifest.getTargetSdkVersion(AndroidManifest.java:485)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.pickSdkVersion(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:149)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 1.
    at org.robolectric.internal.SdkConfig.<init>(SdkConfig.java:38)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:184)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:149)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51663', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 255
```

It says something about my java. The java information is,
[image]

Why does it say

> One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

The entire code is at my github [RobolectricGo](https://github.com/rogerAce/RobolectricGo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are a Mac user. Did you try your project on command line?

There is a nice page with great information how to get started with robolectric: http://robolectric.org/getting-started/ and there you get the following hint.

> Note for Mac Users
>
> If you are on a Mac, you will probably need to configure the default JUnit test runner configuration in order to work around a bug where Android Studio does not set the working directory to the module being tested. This can be accomplished by editing the run configurations, Defaults -> JUnit and changing the working directory value to $MODULE_DIR$.

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows and this was the correct fix for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also try adding

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

and

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

to your test classes.